# mysql join show replicate result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, concatenation

hello stackoverflow community :) ,

I have a complex join query is causing me lots of troubles :/

i have 3 tables here.

1: table [taxonomys t]

```
id  ownerId  type
1   1        office
2   1        inventory
3   1        inventory_item
```

2: table [tax_links l]

```
id  parent  son
1   1        2
2   1        3
```

3: table [settings s]

```
id taxId title     value    type
1  1     name      office1  taxonomy
2  1     location  Address  taxonomy
3  1     settings  on       tax_links
```

so 
 1. **taxonomy table** containes all resourses of a user
 2. **link_taxs** link 2 taxonomys to each others
 3. **settings** save settings for resource , in case i want settings to be related to relations (not global) i set type in settings to tax_links

My query should return all resources of user, and concentrate all related as sons, and the id of relations in relsId.

```
SELECT `t`.`id`, group_concat(l.son) as sons, group_concat(l.id) as relsId, group_concat( s.title ) as titles, group_concat( s.value ) as vals, `t`.`name`, `t`.`type`, group_concat(s.id) as sid
FROM (`taxonomys` t)
LEFT JOIN `tax_links` l ON `l`.`parent` = `t`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `settings` s ON `s`.`taxId` = `t`.`id` and s.table = 'taxonomy'
WHERE `t`.`ownerId` =  1
GROUP BY `t`.`id`
```

it runs perfect, and return all what i need **EXCEPT THAT** it return REPLICATED results in sons,relsId.

for example tables i provided when i run this query i expect the result to be

```
id     sons     relsId     titles          vals
1      2,3      1,2        name,location   office1,address
```

problem is when i run my query it return duplicate content for sons and relsId so i get something like

```
id     sons         relsId     titles          vals
1      2,3,2,3      1,2        name,location   office1,address
                               name,location   office1,address
```

why is this happeing ? i know i can filter array_unique using php after i fetch row, but what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `distinct` keyword in `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT `t`.`id`, group_concat(distinct l.son) as sons,
       group_concat(distinct l.id) as relsId,
       group_concat( s.title ) as titles, group_concat( s.value ) as vals,
       `t`.`name`, `t`.`type`, group_concat(s.id) as sid
```

Comment: is there any problem from running group_concat to aggregate many rows ? my many to many table might grow to 100+ row

Comment: 100 rows is nothing for a database.  100,000 rows is still pretty small.  `group_concat()` does have some limitations on the length of the result string for each row.